# Why was a recent qustion about robin behavior closed?

Tags: discussion

The question [Why do I often see male robins with female robins?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/why-do-i-often-see-male-robins-with-female-robins) was voted closed by several users.  I regard the question as valid, although it would have benefitted from a brief Google search that would have made it more informed.

I find observing and understanding wildlife behavior an integral part of my enjoyment of the outdoors, whether I am in nearby woods or on a backpacking trip thousands of miles from home.

I edited the question to try to make it more relevant to the objectors.  If my edit "worked" fine; if it didn't work, why not?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. I wondered about that question myself, only because it didn't seem very different from other animal behavior questions, including my own! It was really nice of you to help the OP, and hope the question can be taken off hold.  Of course I trust the more experienced users, and will learn from whatever response you get here.

Comment: @Sue Possibly if the same question had been asked about bears or cougars no one would have voted to close it.  But a robin is just...wimpy.

Comment: Thanks to Rory for reopening the question! Your comment on it is very informative, and I'm wondering if you might be willing to write it up as an answer. If not, I completely understand, I'm not saying you should put more work into this than you already have. :)

Comment: @Sue Done, because no ornithologists have stepped forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the edits to the question have improved it, and have to agree with you two - I have now reopened it.